# Why is the vocab size of Byte level BPE smaller than Unicode's vocab size?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, nlp

I recently read GPT2 and the paper says:

> This would result in a base vocabulary of over 130,000 before any multi-symbol tokens are added.  This is prohibitively large compared to the 32,000 to 64,000 token vocabularies often used with BPE. In contrast, a byte-level version of BPE only requires a base vocabulary of size 256.

I really don't understand the words. The number of characters that Unicode represents is 130K but how can this be reduced to 256? Where's the rest of approximately 129K characters? What am I missing? Does byte-level BPE allow duplicating of representation between different characters?

I don't understand the logic. Below are my questions:

- Why the size of vocab is reduced? (from 130K to 256)
- What's the logic of the BBPE (Byte-level BPE)?

---

## Detail question

Thank you for your answer but I really don't get it. Let's say we have 130K unique characters. What we want (and BBPE do) is to reduce this basic (unique) vocabulary. Each Unicode character can be converted 1 to 4 bytes by utilizing UTF-8 encoding. The original paper of BBPE says (Neural Machine Translation with Byte-Level Subwords):

> Representing text at the level of bytes and **using the 256 bytes** set as vocabulary is a potential solution to this issue.

Each byte can represent 256 characters (bits, 2^8), we only need 2^17 (131072) bits for representing the unique Unicode characters. In this case, where did the **256 bytes in the original paper** come from? I don't know both the logic and how to derive this result.

I arrange my questions again, more detail:

- How does BBPE work?
- Why the size of vocab is reduced? (from 130K to 256 bytes)

  - Anyway, we always need 130K space for a vocab. What's the difference between representing unique characters as Unicode and Bytes?

Since I have little knowledge of computer architecture and programming, please let me know if there's something I missed.

Sincerely, thank you.

Comment: *How does BBPE work?* → This is beyond the scope of a Stack OverFlow post. *Why is the size of the vocab reduced?* → Because there are only 256 values a byte can take. *We always need 130K space for the vocab* → No, you can choose any size for the base vocab and for the final one (after applying BPE). In the final vocab, frequent (sub)words will have their own entries; rarer ones will be composed of smaller units, all the way down to the entries from the base vocab.

Comment: @lenz Okay. Then which site is more proper to ask this question?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. Did you have a look at [this blog post](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Byte-Pair-Encoding/)? I think it's quite hands-on.

Comment: @lenz I already read the post and I guess that the post explains BPE rather than BBPE. I understand how BPE works.

Comment: Ok, then take the example word "café" instead of "low". For BPE the segments are `"c a f é </w>"`, but for BBPE they are `b"c a f \xc3 \xa9 </w>"`. So for BBPE you have one more token in this example, but the tokens always have a numerical value <256. The algorithm stays the same.

Comment: The original paper mentioned they are **'using the 256 bytes'** for base vocabulary. But your words **"the tokens always have a numerical value <256"** is about bits right?

Comment: @lenz Um... here's the thing. What I don't understand is the part of the process of BBPE: encoding Unicode code point into Byte-level. We can keep our representation as you mentioned **The algorithm stays the same**, while reducing the base vocabulary size. **Each number must represent/map a unique character to number**: (u+0021 - !). But we need 130K for Unicode (U+xxxx) it reduced when we represent them as bytes? I don't really understand the concept at all.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I think I'm unable to help you. We're going in circles.

Comment: @lenz It's okay. Thanks for helping me. What I just don't get is **tokens always have a numerical value <256**. Why and how? We have 130K (2^17) in Unicode but why we only need 256(2^8) in Bytes ?

Comment: This is my last response: I just stumbled over [this well-written article](https://kunststube.net/encoding/) again, maybe this helps understanding the bytes/characters distinction.

Comment: @lenz Thank you very much. I'll try to understand it. I'm so glad you help me. I wish you all the best. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unicode code points are integers in the range 0..1,114,112, of which roughly 130k are in use at the moment. Every Unicode code point corresponds to a character, like "a" or "λ" or "龙", which is handy to work with in many cases (but there are a lot of complicated details, eg. combining marks).

When you save text data to a file, you use one of the UTFs (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32) to convert code points (integers) to bytes. For UTF-8 (the most popular file encoding), each character is represented by 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes (there's some inner logic to discriminate single- and multi-byte characters).

So when the base vocabulary are bytes, this means that rare characters will be encoded with multiple BPE segments.

#### Example

Let's consider a short example sentence like “That’s great ”.

With a base vocabulary of all Unicode characters, the BPE model starts off with something like this:

```
T      54
h      68
a      61
t      74
’    2019
s      73
       20
g      67
r      72
e      65
a      61
t      74
       20
   1F44D
```

(The first column is the character, the second its codepoint in hexadecimal notation.)

If you first encode this sentence with UTF-8, then this sequence of bytes is fed to BPE instead:

```
T      54
h      68
a      61
t      74
�      e2
�      80
�      99
s      73
       20
g      67
r      72
e      65
a      61
t      74
       20
�      f0
�      9f
�      91
�      8d
```

The typographic apostrophe "’" and the thumbs-up emoji are represented by multiple bytes.

With either input, the BPE segmentation (after training) may end with something like this:

```
Th|at|’s|great|
```

(This is a hypothetical segmentation, but it's possible that capitalised “That“ is too rare to be represented as a single segment.)

The number of BPE operations is different though: to arrive at the segment `’s`, only one merge step is required for code-point input, but three steps for byte input.

With byte input, the BPE segmentation is likely to end up with sub-character segments for rare characters.
The down-stream language model will have to learn to deal with that kind of input.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the nice explanation! However, I still don't understand the logic. Either using Unicode or Byte (UTF-8), it still needs a space of size 130K for saving the **unique characters**. How can BBPE magically reduce the size of unique characters?

Comment: By splitting characters with high code points into multiple bytes. It's not magical. It's like when a burger is too large to bite, so you eat it layer by layer. It's not the same experience because in some bites there's only bread or only salad, but eventually you get everything eaten.

Comment: I really appreciate your nice answers but I can't get it indeed. I understood the vocab size is reduced but I don't know the process.  I'm so sorry. Could you please add more detail and examples of the process of BBPE? Thank you for your help again. I add more detail on my question.

Answer (score 2):

I understand the confusion you are/were facing. Your question made me re-think what the author meant in their paper. I think this is my understanding of how BBPE handles the encoding.

> The number of characters that Unicode represents is 130K but how can this be reduced to 256?

I think the confusion starts here, Unicode has different ways of encoding data (UTF-8, UTF-16, ...) (I am referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003178/size-of-characters-in-unicode)) which use different number of bytes for their representations, the 130k unicode symbols are all strings of 1, 2 or 4 bytes (whatever the encoding method defines it to have).

Now BBPE is said to work on **byte level**. What this means is for a given character 'c' (let's say in english), if a unicode representation uses 2 bytes, then in a BBPE encoded format - it can be represented by two 256 dimensional vectors (2 bytes equivalent).

So coming back to what the paper said:

> In contrast, a byte-level version of BPE only requires a base vocabulary of size 256.

They are referring to a byte representation, since anything encoded in unicode can be broken down to some `n bytes` - which in base (minimum) case can be just 1 byte. **In base case**, we have to deal with just 1 byte, and we know we can have 256 different 1 byte representations.

Hence, the 256 base vocabulary in BBPE.

Comment: I think you are right. Each byte can represents 2^8=256 characters so the base vocab size will be 256. Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score -2):

So you already know the BPE right Byte-level BPE is an improvisation of how the base vocabulary is defined. Recall, there is 1,43,859 unicode characters in unicode alphabets, but wonder how the gpt-2 vocabulary size is just 50,257. Having a base vocabulary of 1.4L will increase the size even more during the training process(where we will combine frequent occuring unicode characters).

To solve this issue GPT-2 uses a byte-level process which has a base vocabulary of just 256 characters using which any unicode characters can be represented by either a single or multiple byte-level characters. I still dont know the process of how a unicode character is converted to byte-level representation.

Does this explanation gave you a clarity why we go to a byte-level representation. Once again gpt-2 uses this 256 base vocabulary and increase the vocabulary size by adding frequent co occuring characters.